# Spectrum of a convolution operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, convolution

For context, this question is related to a [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4726675) of mine.

Consider the operator $H$ acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and of the form $$Hv:=\phi\ast v,$$ where  $\phi=e^{-|x|}/2$ and $\ast$ denotes the convolution operation. Since $\phi$ is the Green's function for $1-\partial_x^2$, we have that
$$(1-\partial_x^2)(\phi\star v)=v.\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

From (1), the eigenvalue problem $Hv=\lambda v$ is equivalent to
$$
v''=(1-1/\lambda)\,v.\;\;\;\;(2)
$$
Because (2) does not have $L^2$ solutions, $H$ does not have point spectrum. Intuitively/heuristically, I find the essential spectrum by using Fourier analysis on (2), with $v=e^{ikx}$ and find the dispersion relation
$$
\lambda=\frac{1}{1+k^2}.
$$
Thus I have the following result: The spectrum of $H$ is the interval $[0,1]$ and it  entirely consists of essential spectrum.

Are my proof and result valid? I am asking because I find the proof to be heuristic thus have some doubts. Perhaps somebody can help me with the validity (or invalidity) of one of them?

Comment: I think that doing the computation via the Fourier transform, as is also explained here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117098/spectrum-of-convolution-integral-operator, is perfectly fine.

Comment: @C.Hamster Thanks. That link is really useful.