# Spectrum of a sum of self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

This is a "sequel" to [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807079/essential-spectrum-of-an-convolution-and-function-multiplying-operator) where I explain why I need the spectrum of an operator given as the sum of a convolution and a function multiplication. Here, I am considering the following theorem, which would solve the issue.

**Theorem**. Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two bounded self-adjoint operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Assume the spectra of $L_1$ and $L_2$, respectively, are the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[a,b]$. Then we have the following

1. $a\leq \frac{\left<v,(L_1+L_2)v\right>}{||v||^2}\leq 1+b$
2. $\sigma(L_1+L_2)\subset [a,1+b],$

where $<.,.>$ and $||.||$ denote the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ inner product and norm.

**Idea of proof.** Since $L_i$ are self-adjoint, and given their spectra, we have that

1. $0\leq \frac{\left<v,L_1v\right>}{||v||^2}\leq 1$
2. $a\leq \frac{\left<v,L_2v\right>}{||v||^2}\leq b.$

Then statement 1 in the theorem is implied from 1 and 2 above. Because $L_i$ are self-adjoint, statements 1 and 2 in the theorem are equivalent.

**Ideas and questions.** I found [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1997004) that does it in general (not necessarily s-a or bounded) for the "Fredholm spectrum" under a condition ($L_1L_2$ compact) I can verify. I checked that the Fredholm is the essential spectrum, which is what I have.

Then I found this more [recent paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/banach-journal-of-mathematical-analysis/volume-8/issue-1/On-the-essential-spectrum-of-the-sum-of-self-adjoint/10.15352/bjma/1381782087.full) about bounded s-a operators, where the authors improve a result that says that under the same condition as above, the essential spectrum of the sum is the sum of the essential spectra (minus the zero eigenvalue).

Is what I need in the theorem trivial? Does my idea of proof make sense? Is the result in the second paper what I should be using?

If I understand the second paper correctly, that would mean that the inequalities in my theorem are actually equalities and $\subset$ can be replaced by $=$.

It seems like everything works out well but I wanted someone who feels more confident with those topics to take a look at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is fine. The numbers you use are what is known as the *numerical range* of an operator. It is a basic fact that the spectrum of an operator is contained in the closure of the numerical range. So you show that the numerical range is contained in $[a,1+b]$, which then implies that $\sigma(L_1+L_2)\subset[a,1+b]$.

The inclusion $\sigma(A+B)\subset\sigma(A)+\sigma(B)$ for commuting $A,B$ holds, but equality usually fails. I can only see the abstract of the second paper you mention; what I can say is that the equality in the abstract is not true in general (note in any case that the paper uses the **union** of the spectra and not their sum). Consider
$$
A_0=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad B_0=\begin{bmatrix} 3&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\sigma(A_0)=\{0,1\}$, $\sigma(B_0)=\{0,3\}$, and $\sigma(A_0+B_0)=\{0,4\}$. This is neither $\sigma(A_0)+\sigma(B_0)=\{0,1,3,4\}$ nor $\sigma(A_0)\cup\sigma(B_0)=\{0,1,3\}$. You do have $\sigma(A_0+B_0)\subset\sigma(A_0)+\sigma(B_0)$.

You could also consider
$$
A_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad B_1=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\sigma(A_1)=\{0,1\}$, $\sigma(B_1)=\{0,3\}$, and $\sigma(A_1+B_1)=\{1,3\}$. This is not $\sigma(A_0)+\sigma(B_0)=\{0,1,3,4\}$; but you do have $$\sigma(A_1+B_1)\setminus\{0\}=\{1,3\}=(\sigma(A_1)\cup\sigma(B_1))\setminus\{0\}.$$

These examples can be easily turned into examples about the essential spectrum by considering $A=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N}A_0$ and $B=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N}B_0$ and similarly for $A_1$ and $B_1$.

What the examples show is the fact that the spectrum will never tell you the "position" of the operator. A selfadjoint operator is described by its spectrum together with its spectral projections (or spectral measure in infinite-dimension). Two selfadjoint operators that commute will have the same spectral projections, but the location of the eigenvalues can be different, as the two examples show. This leads to different possibilities for the spectrum of the sum.

Comment: Thank you so much. My second paper says the equality holds if the composition of the operators is compact. What I just realized is that that paper talks about the union of the spectra, not the sum, which is different. So I am a little confused about that paper and its result right now.

Comment: Yes, that makes a difference. That the product is compact means that it is zero in the Calkin. So when you look at the essential spectrum you have selfadjoint operators such that their pairwise products are zero. This means that you are in a version of my $A_1,B_1$, which is the case where the equality works.

Comment: OK, thanks to you, I understand that the equality works when that condition (product being compact) is satisfied. Thank you for all your time but if I can ask you one more thing. What troubles me is that you and I, and the older paper, talk about the "addition" of the spectra, while this most recent paper talks about the "union" of the spectra, which is different. I cannot reconcile the results. Perhaps the newer paper means something different and it may be a notation thing. I read but I cannot see how can a result giving the addition and another one with union be both true.

Comment: In general, you cannot relate the spectra. For instance, $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad B=\frac12\,\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix},$$ then $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)=\{0,1\}$ while $\sigma(A+B)=\{\frac{2\pm\sqrt2}2\}$. Both papers have a commutation relation. When $AB=0$ you are in a situation like my second example and you get the condition with the union. When $AB=BA$, what you can say is that $\sigma(A+B)=\sigma(A)+\sigma(B)$.  *(continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* There is no contradiction because to have the situation where $AB=0$ you have $0\in\sigma(A)$ and $0\in\sigma(A)$, so $\sigma(A)\cup\sigma(B)\subset \sigma(A)+\sigma(B)$ as the second paper says.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense and I understand! Again, I really appreciate your help.